# unwanted confirmation sms sent by provider in Austria

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager

I have a strange problem with sending SMS.

My app just uses SMSManager like recommended everywhere:

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

While this works perfectly everywhere there is a strange behaviour only in Austria.

In Austria the providers can send confirmation SMS that confirm that a SMS was actually sent. This incurrs additional charges.

One can turn off this confirmation either in the Android phone itself or with the provider directly.

While this works if an SMS is beeing sent manually, some users report  that SMS sent through the app always cause confirmation messages sent by the provider - which is unwanted.

Do you have any idea how that can happen?
I always though that sending SMS through the standard SMSManager on Android is exactly the same as manually sending SMS.

Is there a possible solution for this so the SMS sent through apps will not cause confirmation SMS to be triggered by the provider like manually sent SMS?

The problems were reported with Samsung S2, S3 and HTC phones, providers t-mobile or A1. The caller and the callee both are in Austria with Austrian SIM.

There are many users of the app in Austria - the problem has been reported couple of times. I have not yet found any commonalities.

Many thanks for all your hints....